# Binary operator+ with lambda for custom pseudo-statement

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++11, dsl

I am trying to do some "pseudo-statement in c++11", using visual studio 2012 compiler.
Given an interface, if my class is a mock class, it will execute the statements between
the delimited braces.

Basically, I want this to be allowed:

```
when_mock(my_object) {
    //Set expectations here
}
```

I have a class that looks similar to this:

```
        template <class Iface>
           struct MockScope {


              MockScope(Iface & obj)
              : mObj(&obj) {}


              template <class Func>
              void operator+(Func && f) {
                  mFunc = func;
              }


              ~MockScope() { 
                   using psy::testing::MockClass; 
                   auto i = dynamic_cast<typename 
                      MockClass<Iface>::type*>(mObj); 
                   if (i) 
                      mFunc(*i); 
               } 

           private:
              Iface * mObj;
              std::function<void
              (typename psy::testing::MockClass<Iface>::type &)> mFunc;
           };

template <class Iface>
MockScope<Iface> make_mock_scope(Iface & iface) {
   MockScope<> scope(iface);
   return scope;
}
```

And a macro:

```
#define when_mock(obj) \
make_mock_scope(obj) + \
[](MockClass<std::decay<decltype(obj)>::type>::type \
& mock_obj)  -> void \
```

When I write this code:

```
auto & interface = object.GetMyInterface();

when_mock(interface) {}
```

I get this compilation error ---> `missing ';' before '}'` under visual studio 2012.
If I remove `when_mock` it compiles.

- Am I trying something illegal or it is a compiler bug?
- How could I enable this syntax in any other way?

Comment: Have you looked at the preprocessed file? `Properties > C++ > Preprocessor > Generate preprocessed file`. Or have you tried expanding the macro "by hand" to see where the error is really reported?

Comment: Are you sure you have the line-continuation character at the end of the macro? What happens if you remove the last backslash from the macro body?

Comment: Also note that you will have to terminate the "statement" with a `;` when using it.

Comment: @Angew I am using nmake at this point. Though I could generate a vs2012 solution maybe, since I am relying on cmake as the build system. I will report later.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did. Same result.

Comment: No need to generate solution - just pass `/P` flag to compilation.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem, as @Angew commented, was on not putting a ; at the end of the statement.

- Is it possible to get rid of this annoying `;`, though it is minor?

I will mark as solved after having an informed reply.